# PHP FFI - return array from Rust function back to PHP

Tags: php, rust, ffi, php-ffi

I need to return few values from rust function. Tried to declare function which returns an array

```
$ffi = FFI::cdef('float get_arr()[2];', './target/release/libphp_rust.dylib');

$array = $ffi->get_arr();
```

But got an error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught FFI\ParserException: function returning array is not allowed at line 1 in /array.php:3`

It seems PHP FFI can't work with arrays directly. So I found another solution.
I created C-array from PHP, then passed pointer to it to Rust code and then populated it with Rust function:

```
$ffi = FFI::cdef('bool get_arr(float (*res)[2]);', './target/release/libphp_rust.dylib');

$array = $ffi->new('float[2]');

$result = $ffi->get_arr(FFI::addr($array));

if ($result) {
    var_dump($array);
} else {
    //... something went wrong
}
```

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn get_arr(array_pointer: *mut [f32;2]) -> bool {
    let res = unsafe {
        assert!(!array_pointer.is_null());
        &mut *array_pointer
    };

    res[0] = 0.1;
    res[1] = 0.2;

    return true;
}
```

This solutions seems to work correct but i have some doubts about it:

1. Is passing pointers to FFI safe enough and what problems may I face with this in future?
2. Are Rust arrays fully C-compatible so that I'm able to assign value to it directly by index?
3. I there better way to achieve what I need? Or maybe are there some good practices about passing complex data structures with FFI?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules surrounding this are still up in the air, so your example is questionably safe. This should be ok, but requires nightly features:

```rust
#![feature(maybe_uninit_extra)]
#![feature(ptr_as_uninit)]

// Make sure you use `extern "C"`. `extern` alone means `extern "Rust"`.
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_arr(array_pointer: *mut [f32; 2]) -> bool {
    let fat: *mut [f32] = array_pointer;
    let res = unsafe { fat.as_uninit_slice_mut().unwrap() };

    res[0].write(0.1);
    res[1].write(0.2);

    true
}
```

On the stable channel it's just less elegant:

```rust
// Make sure you use `extern "C"`. `extern` alone means `extern "Rust"`.
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_arr(array_pointer: *mut [f32; 2]) -> bool {
    assert!(!array_pointer.is_null());
    unsafe {
        let res = array_pointer as *mut f32;
        res.add(0).write(0.1);
        res.add(1).write(0.2);
    }

    true
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain, what do we need this line for? `let fat: *mut [f32] = array_pointer;`

Comment: Sure, it's just to coerce `*mut [f32; 2]` into `*mut [f32]` (a fat pointer) in order to use the method [`<*mut [T]>::as_uninit_slice_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_uninit_slice_mut). For whatever reason, it seems Rust doesn't do this automatically.

Comment: If you want, you can remove that line and just set `res` using: `let res = unsafe { <*mut [f32]>::as_uninit_slice_mut(array_pointer).unwrap() };`.

Comment: I was a bit stumped by this and did some more digging, and it turns out [this is actually a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74679)!

Comment: OK, got it... then another question... why would i need fat pointer here if i'm pretty sure my array should have only 2 values? are there any advantages using fat pointers instead of pointer to fixed-size array in this particular case? I'm newbie to rust as much as to all this pointers stuff so just trying to get the point. Thanks

Comment: All slices are fat pointers, so really what it's doing is just coercing `&[f32; 2]` to `&[f32]` since `as_uninit_slice_mut` only supports slices, not arrays. I guess you could always just use `let res = unsafe { (array_pointer as *mut [MaybeUninit<f32>; 2]).as_mut().unwrap() };`.

Comment: I still don't get why do we need MaybeUninit here, because my code works well without it. Is it a good practice to use it for all external pointers just to ensure safety? And if i pass null pointer from external code it would be initialized in rust runtime? Did i get it right?

Comment: Or does it simply allow to work with nullable C datatypes?

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb :-/

Comment: Memory coming from C should be initialized, "uninitialized memory" only really applies to memory *created* in the Rust runtime. The problem here is that in Rust, when you cast a type to a reference, you assume that it is valid for that reference. For example, if you have a pointer to the number 3 and you cast the pointer as `&bool`, that is UB. I'm not sure if floats are valid for all bit patterns, but either way better safe than sorry!

Comment: To elaborate just a bit: it's currently not decided whether or not simply creating a reference to an invalid value is UB (so currently you must assume that it's considered UB), but that's moot anyway: writing `res[0] = 0.1` essentially desugars to `let mut res0: &mut f32 = &mut res[0]; *res0 = 0.1` and I'm pretty sure assigning to an invalid reference is UB (although since `f32` doesn't have `Drop` glue, I'm not 100% sure). Bottom line is better safe than sorry! Btw you don't actually need `MaybeUninit`; using `ptr.write()` (like in the 2nd example) is fine, just requires more `unsafe` code.

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said about C. Memory is usually zeroed out, but that's not always the case (especially not for memory on the heap!) and plus, I don't think there's any guarantee that all zeroes is always a valid bit pattern. So treat all uninitialized memory as uninitialized, and don't touch it until you've initialized it with `ptr.write()` or `MaybeUninit::write`.